# Match Error on List.collect

Tags: scala

What's wrong with the second implementation?

**Works:**

```
scala> List(1,2,3).collect{ case i: Int if i % 2 == 0 => i }
res1: List[Int] = List(2)
```

**Doesn't:**

```
scala> val evens = PartialFunction[Any, Int]{
     | case i: Int if i % 2 == 0 => i
     | }
evens: PartialFunction[Any,Int] = <function1>

scala> List(1,2,3).collect{evens}
scala.MatchError: 1 (of class java.lang.Integer)
    at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:7)
    at $anonfun$1.apply(<console>:7)
    at scala.PartialFunction$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:242)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:278)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
    ...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should create `evens` `PartialFunction` like this:

```
val evens: PartialFunction[Any, Int] = {
  case i: Int if i % 2 == 0 => i
}
```

With `PartialFunction[Any, Int]{ ... }` you are calling an `apply` method of object `PartialFunction`. It defined like this:

```
def apply[A, B](f: (A) ⇒ B): PartialFunction[A, B]
```

So `{ case i: Int if i % 2 == 0 => i }` is used as a function, not a `PartialFunction` and `evens` is defined at any argument:

```
scala> val evens = PartialFunction[Any, Int]{
     |   case i: Int if i % 2 == 0 => i
     | }

scala> evens.isDefinedAt(1)
res1: Boolean = true

scala> val evens: PartialFunction[Any, Int] = {
     |   case i: Int if i % 2 == 0 => i
     | }

scala> evens.isDefinedAt(1)
res5: Boolean = false
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code actually does work on Scala 2.9.2 (modulo incorrect partial function declaration). However, in any case the reason is probably the type signature:

```
PartialFunction[Any, Int]
```

Since the first type parameter is `Any`, the collection elements get autoboxed to `java.lang.Integer` instances - it even says so in the stack trace (by necessity, since `Any` corresponds to `Object`). However, you're matching for `Int`, and this causes the error.

Using `PartialFunction[Int, Int]` should solve the problem, i.e.:

```
val evens:PartialFunction[Int, Int] = {case i: Int if i % 2 == 0 => i}
```